# Listeners are down on the Queuemanager (IBM Websphere MQv7)

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I have connected to remote queue manager which has a bunch of queue's. But the Queue listeners (Open Input Count) are not showing up. The Tomcat Application server is up and running.

What could be the possible reason ?

Is there a way i can check the reason why the listeners are down ?

Comment: Hello folks ! Can anybody help me out please

Answer (score 0):

I think further detail is required. I would assume the qmgr is fine as you say you have connected to a remote queue manager which has a bunch of queues. check the queu

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to look on the [WebSphere MQ Infocenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/index.jsp), you will find tons of valuable information. Nevertheless I will say that you have to check your Error [logs](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/fa15170_.htm), normally you'll check: 
- The Queue manager Error Logs.
- The general WebSphere MQ Logs.
The directories depends on the platform, but Infocenter will be your friend on that!

I'm not sure what you mean when you say Queue Listeners, perhaps your intention is to refer to Queue manager Listener (for example for TCP) on certain IP port. If possible include the Completion Code and Reason code, or even the Stack Trace you get in Java.

I honestly hope this can be useful, let me know if it wasn't!

Have fun and Good luck!